# Validate links with php

Tags: php

Can anyone tell me if its possible to validate a link with php? By validate, I mean check if the link is active and works not just the actual format of the link.

Comment: Check this out. http://www.tutorialcode.com/php/link-verifier-check-if-a-url-is-valid-or-not/

Comment: Check out [this thread on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/408405/easy-way-to-test-a-url-for-404-in-php).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to do a HEAD request and check the response. 200 indicates the request succeeded. There are others that can be [found here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) that you may want to treat as valid. (301 and 302 redirects spring to mind)

If you use cURL, you could use something like this

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch,  CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE); //Include the headers
curl_setopt($ch,  CURLOPT_NOBODY, TRUE); //Make HEAD request

$response = curl_exec($ch);

if ( $response === false ){
    //something went wrong, assume not valid
}

//list of status codes you want to treat as valid:    
$validStatus = array(200, 301, 302, 303, 307);

if( !in_array(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE), $validStatus) ) {
    //the HTTP code is not valid. The url is not valid
}

curl_close($ch);
```