# PHP Curl get HTTP code, not whole document

Tags: php, curl, http-response-codes

I'm using curl in PHP to check the HTTP code when requesting some files, I'm trying to make my speed run faster so I'm wondering is there a way to make it get the HTTP code without actually getting the web page from the remote host

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set `CURLOPT_NOBODY` to true. This means that rather than preforming a GET or POST request,  a HEAD request will be preformed so the remote server will only return the HTTP header.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
```

There is also some example code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539926/validate-links-with-php/2539983#2539983)

Comment: Thanks for that. I was sure I've done it before but I just couldn't find it! Got my script down from 20 seconds to 7 seconds.