# CURL vs fopen vs fsocketopen?

Tags: php

I would write a WordPress plugin to parse all image source and check it's broken link or not.
My idea is :

1. Select all post&page's images by regex from MySQL
2. Navigate the image url and get the response header (404 ,403 error etc)
3. print a report

Since i don't need actual to download the binary file, so in performance ,compare in CURL , fopen , fsocketopen
Which one is worst to use?

And one more question, which method can execute in multi-thread?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cost of opening a connection to the remote server makes the performance of the library a fairly moot point. In other words it isn't worth worrying about the performance of the functions.

A better option would be to use wse whatever function allows you to make HEAD requests (Which only return the HTTP headers). While you can do it with `fsockopen` (I don't know about `fopen`), it is a lot of work when cURL has code already written to send the request and parse the response.

For an example of how to do a head request using [cURL see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644624/php-curl-get-http-code-not-whole-document/2644663#2644663).

> And one more question, which method can execute in multi-thread?

PHP doesn't have threads

Comment: While it's true that php isn't threaded as such, please be sure to read up on the curl_multi* functions (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php), as it IS possible to pull multiple curl requests in parallel. For a more in-depth read on how one might go about this, may I highly recommend Stoyan Stefanov's write up: (http://www.phpied.com/simultaneuos-http-requests-in-php-with-curl/)