# PHP Simple HTML DOM If Website is Down

Tags: php, html, parsing, html-parsing, simple-html-dom

I'm parsing some news from one of the Turkish Health Ministry's websites. But for instance if website is down now or can't be loaded,  my website doesn't load the content after the part that i parse the news. Is there a way to reduce the parsing time ( because of the problem, my website gets loaded in 1 minute nearly ) and if it returns null, just write something like, can't make connection or something like that error message ?

```
<?php
$html = file_get_html('http://www.tkhk.gov.tr/TR,6/duyurular.html');
$i = 0;
foreach($html->find('a.belge_alt_b') as $element2){
echo "<div class=\"post\">
<div class=\"matter\">
<h3><a target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://www.tkhk.gov.tr".$element2->href." \">". $element2->plaintext . "</a></h3> 
</div>
</div>
";
$i++ ;
if($i > 4) break;
}
?>
```

Comment: think like you need the stock exchange values. won't you parse them ? this is just like that.

Comment: Why not just load a place holder like "Loading content" and use `ajax` to load the specific content?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PHP curl library instead of `file_get_html()` and set the timeout appropriately.  [Setting Curl's Timeout in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582057/setting-curls-timeout-in-php)

Comment: If the OP wants to stick with `file_get_html()`, then he could use curl to check the status code first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539926/validate-links-with-php/2539983#2539983

Comment: @jk. - that is fine, except then he'd be making two requests, when he could just make one.

Comment: Agreed, just thought I throw that out there.