# Check whether a HTML page exists

Tags: php, fopen

I want to check whether a HTML page exists on another site. More exactly, my users need to upload a `.html` page onto their own site and after that they need to press "verify now" on my site. My site then needs to confirm that the html page exists on their site.

I found this code:

```
$url = 'http://domain.tld/my_page.html';
$handle = @fopen($url,'r');
if($handle !== false){
   echo 'Page Exists';
}  else {
   echo 'Page Not Found';
}
```

But if `my_page.html` don't exist, this code returns just "Page Exists".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have the `curl` extension installed in your PHP, I think this by far your best option:
[Easy way to test a URL for 404 in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408405/easy-way-to-test-a-url-for-404-in-php/408416#408416)

Comment: Thank you, I found the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT 1**:
sorry fo edditing... do not get the question an first.

you need to understand that server will answer in any way. you just need to check then responsed code, not response text. or to parse text.

in your case server answer like follow:

```
Object not found!

 The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again. 

 If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster. 
Error 404
work.local
Thu Jul 28 13:22:49 2011
 Apache/2.2.15 (Linux/SUSE)
```

**Edit 2** :
you may want better to use [socket_connect](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-connect.php) instead of fopen to check if the file exist

Answer (score 1):

A webserver returns the 404 HTTP status code if a resource does not exists. Resource is the html file in your question.

You can do a head request to the server to learn about the status - or just a get request.

PHP has a function build in for this operation as well, it's called [`get_headers`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php) ([Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/D47OOD)):

```
$headers = get_headers($url, 1);
$statusLine = $headers[0];
list(,$statusCode) = explode(' ', $statusLine, 3);
```

Comment: Yes, but for example, if on .htaccess site have "ErrorDocument 404 http://domain.tld" this will don't works.

Comment: It will always work if the servers send correct response headers. That is normally the case for own ErrorDocument settings for 404 as well. However if the error page is changing response headers to 200 OK, then nothing (that includes the curl method) will work but inspecting the return HTTP body for a specific error pattern.