# Getting HTTP response of a URL in PHP - XML

Tags: php, xml, httpresponse

I am trying to retrieve the status of the url. I am writing php code to retrieve it but i am not getting the output. Nothing is being displayed.

I am reading the url's from the xml file and storing it in variable. I am doing

```
file_get_contents($url);

echo $http_respone_header[0];
```

`$url` contains the url which i have read from the xml file.

Comment: You have a typo in `http_respone_header` - maybe that solves the problem already?

Comment: THIS ISNT COPY-PASTED FROM THE CODE.....the typo is only here, in the question, the code is correctly spelt.

Comment: What does `print_r($http_response_header);` show?

Comment: if i write $file=file_get_contents($url); then also i am not getting the output. its not displaying anything. i don't know what is the problem.

Comment: $url contains a url retrieved from an xml file...and that has no issues, cos it is echoing the url correctly, also that url when manually entered in a browser works fine

Comment: Strange, then I don't know what the problem could be. But you should definitely show your *real* copy + pasted code

Answer (score 1):

The thing You are doing is not getting URL status but content of the site. In case of wrong/invalid URL file_get_contents() returns false as it is described in documentation [in here](http://pl.php.net/file_get_contents)

If You are trying to get status You can simply use the solution described in other topic on this site.

```
<?php

$url = 'http://www.wp.pl';
$handle = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($handle,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

/* Get the HTML or whatever is linked in $url. */
$response = curl_exec($handle);

/* Check for 404 (file not found). */
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

echo $httpCode;

curl_close($handle);


?>
```

Link to the mentioned topic: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408405/easy-way-to-test-a-url-for-404-in-php)