# PHP Curl get server response

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Easy way to test a URL for 404 in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408405/easy-way-to-test-a-url-for-404-in-php)

I am using curl to download a sequence of pdfs from the backend in PHP. I do not know when the sequence ends like 1.pdf, 2.pdf......etc.

Below is the code I am using to download pdf:

```
$url  = 'http://<ip>.pdf';
    $path = "C:\\test.pdf";
 
    $fp = fopen($path, 'w');
 
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
 
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    
    fclose($fp);
```

But how do I determine that that pdf do not exists in the backend? Does curl returns any response when file not found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ch=curl_init("www.example.org/example.pdf");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,0);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

with `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);` it will return the result on success, FALSE on failure.

with `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,false);` it will return TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.

Moreover, for `file not found`:

```
$http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if($http_code == 404)
{
  /*file not found*/
}
```

Comment: Thanks! curl_getinfo($url, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just test the statut code of the http response after `$data = curl_exec($ch);`

```
$http_status = curl_getinfo($url, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if($http_status == '404') {

   //not found, -> file doesnt exist in your backend
}
```

More info [here](http://frankkoehl.com/2009/09/http-status-code-curl-php/)