# How can I print server's response in Google Admin SDK?

Tags: php, http, google-admin-sdk

I have written a PHP script that uses `curl_seopt` to send data to a server (www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users).

Now I want to know what response did I get? Hopefully "200 OK". How can I print that response or some helpful information to the screen?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14504191/php-curl-get-server-response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ch=curl_init("www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,0);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

with `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);` it will return the result on success, FALSE on failure.

with `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,false);` it will return TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.