# Log curl redirects using CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION set to true

Tags: php, curl

I have an script that grabs content from third party sites and if the url is not found the site redirects with a 302 header location to a custom not found webpage instead of sending a 404 not found. The script also caches the content returned by curl_exec but i don't want to cache the error pages, so is there a way to log those redirects if i have turned on CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION? How can i solve this situation? I know i could just find the error message using a dom parser and if found just discard it, but i want to know if there is other ways to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up disabling followlocation so i just have to catch the 302 code and if it's present i don't cache the page. Thought there would be a way of catching all codes before curl redirects.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Easy way to test a URL for 404 in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408405/easy-way-to-test-a-url-for-404-in-php)

Then using that, just do not cache the page if there is a 404

Comment: Maybe you did not understand, my fault, but the third party site don't throw a 404 instead a 302 to an error page.

Answer (score 0):

See here:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php

This provides such data. This feature is built into this class:

http://semlabs.co.uk/journal/object-oriented-curl-class-with-multi-threading

Comment: getinfo only shows data of the redirected location so dosen't accomplish waht i need. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I see. I think you will need to turn FOLLOWLOCATION off. Downlaod each URL, use get_info() to check if the header is in the 3xx range, if so, log the URL, elseif the header is in the 2xx range, you have your destination page, else an error has occured.