# PHP: Echo inside a Text Area?

Tags: javascript, php, html

currently I am working on a username checker. I am trying to get all the available usernames to echo into a textarea, the only problem is that because the textarea is within a function and an 'if' statement, instead of the code displaying all available usernames into 1 single text area, because the textarea is inside the function and 'if' statement, the textarea continues to produce with every username checked.

Live example of the problem: http://hawkgen.com/ogpost/

Code: (second textarea is the one producing the problem)

```
<?php

function getTitle($Url){
    $str = file_get_contents($Url);
    if(strlen($str)>0){
    preg_match("/\<title\>(.*)\<\/title\>/",$str,$title);
    return $title[1];
    }
    else
    return '404';
}
?>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
<textarea name="notes" value="username" rows="4" cols="50">
test
test1
test2
test3
test4
test5
</textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php
$convert = explode("\r\n", $_POST["notes"]);

for ($i=0;$i<count($convert);$i++) 
{
    if (strlen($convert[$i])>0) {
        $resultCheck = getTitle("http://www.youtube.com/" . $convert[$i]);
        if (strpos($resultCheck,'404') !== false) {
?>
<textarea id="myText" rows="10" cols="40">
<?php 
echo $convert[$i]; 
echo "\n"; 
?>
</textarea>
            <?php
        }
        else {

        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: what's the expected output?

Comment: Don't you just need to move the `<textarea>` tags outside the `for` loop?

Comment: The code is supposed to output all available usernames into ONE textarea, but the code is looping and creating multiple.

I have tried to move the tags outside, but failed in doing so. If you have an example of moving the tags it would be greatly appreciated, as maybe I did it wrong.

Comment: if you want only ONE, create only ONE... post the code where you actually tried it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *andrewsi* mentioned in the comments of your post, you can just aggregate the usernames in a loop and then display them together outside of the loop, like so:

```
$usernames = array();
for ($i=0;$i<count($convert);$i++) 
{
    if (strlen($convert[$i])>0) {
        $resultCheck = getTitle("http://www.youtube.com/" . $convert[$i]);
        if (strpos($resultCheck,'404') !== false) {
            $usernames[] = $convert[$i];
        }
    }
}

echo '<textarea id="myText" rows="10" cols="40">' . implode("\n", $usernames) . '</textarea>';
```

Comment: Try to use cURL to get a URL's http status. [Easy way to test a URL for 404 in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/408416/685326)

Answer (score 1):

If you want one text area tag and loop of content, then you need to put your for loop inside the text area.

```
<textarea><? foreach($convert as $i): ?><?= $i."\r\n" ?><? endforeach ?></textarea>
```