# PHP URL Error Handing

Tags: php, apache, fopen

I'm trying to find a way to handle any 4xx and 5xx error status codes throw by a url like Apache 404 error. I'd like to execute the contents of the if statement only if there are no error status codes thrown by the server.

Using the following if statement it seems that even with the hosted content not being found and throwing an Apache 404 error its still running the contents of the if statement.

```
if (@fopen('http://example','r')){
            use resource
}
else{
use other resources
}
```

is there a better way to ensure the url is available before running it?

Edit: 
i can't use curl in this instance.

thanks

Comment: Use curl and make HEAD call?

Comment: There are no such things as errors, there are only status codes that required url returns.

Comment: I can't use curl, i wish i could. I was under the impression that  4xx and 5xx status codes where called Error status codes. Sorry i should of been more clear.

Comment: Check the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/408420/3049065) which is related to your expectation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $headers = get_headers($url, 1);
  if ($headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK') {//no error status codes thrown by the server
   $data = file_get_contents($url);
   //Do something
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
  $headers = @get_headers($url, 1);
  if ($headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK') {
  //valid 
  }
   if($headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {
    // not found
   }   
  if ($headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently') {
  //moved or redirect page
  }
```

get_headers() manual:http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php