# Determine if a page is a result of being redirected from a 404 Not Found code

Tags: php, redirect, http-status-code-404, system-variable

I would like to display some addition text on a page if its a result of a 404 Not Found code.  I'd like to reuse the rest of page somewhere else.

```
<div>
   <?php
      if(page_is_404_redirect)
      {
         <div>Oh no, I couldn't find what you were looking for.</div>
      }  
   >?
   ...
</div>
```

I didnt find anything on the [$_SERVER variable page](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) that seemed to indicate the error code result.  How can I check the error code status?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Easy way to test a URL for 404 in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/408405/easy-way-to-test-a-url-for-404-in-php)

Comment: @Jay - I'm not hosting this, so I'll have to see if the curl library is setup.  Thanks for the link

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$previous = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$headers = @get_headers($previous);
if($headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found')
{
echo "Previous page was 404 error";
}
?>
```