# PHP file_exists else

Tags: php, image

When I use to following PHP code;

```
<?php if (file_exists("/foto/Maurice.jpg"))
{
echo "<center><img src='/foto/Maurice.jpg'/></center>";
}
else {
echo "<center><img src='/afbeeldingen/kaars1.png'/></center>"; 
?>
```

My browser always shows `kaars1.png`
instead of `Maurice.jpg`
I also tried `!file_exists` but then it doesn't show `kaars1.png`, when `Maurice.jpg` doesn't exist.
Is there a simpel way to fix this?

Comment: `file_exists` is *only* for files on your server's (local) filesystem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can one check to see if a remote file exists using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/981954/how-can-one-check-to-see-if-a-remote-file-exists-using-php)

Comment: give the full url in `file_exist`.(full path where your images exist)

Comment: Just for the sake of asking, are you sure the file actually exists and is accessible by php?

Comment: Is this file you are tesing for located on your server?

Comment: Yes it is on my local server @RiggsFolly

Comment: Then use `if (file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'foto/Maurice.jpg')) { ... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This is an answer to your second question*

The correct solution depends upon your actual directory structure and the location of the script file in relation to the actual folder and file you are looking for, but to start finding a solution the `/` in `"/foto/Maurice.jpg"` say go back to the root directory and look for a directory called `/foto`

So if this folder is under your DocumentRoot try using

```
if (file_exists("foto/Maurice.jpg"))
```

Answer (score 4):

`file_exists` is only for files on your server's (local) filesystem.  You need to actually try to request the URL and see if it exists or not.

You can use cURL to do this.

```
$handle = curl_init('https://picathartes.com/foto/Maurice.jpg');
curl_setopt($handle,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_NOBODY, TRUE);
$response = curl_exec($handle);

// Check for 404 (file not found).
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if($httpCode == 404) {
    echo "<center><img src='https://picathartes.com/afbeeldingen/kaars1.png'/></center>"; 
}   
else{
    echo "<center><img src='https://picathartes.com/foto/Maurice.jpg'/></center>";
} 
curl_close($handle);
```

<sub>(Code from this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/408416)</sub>

Comment: It might work better to not include the actual body of the response (curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1)

Comment: @georaldc: Possibly.  I mostly just "borrowed" the code from another question.  Just getting the header without the body seems like a good idea.

Comment: Its a nice answer, but what makes you think that the file being looked for is on another server?

Comment: Well there you go http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34957526/php-file-exists-else?noredirect=1#comment57647210_34957526

Comment: @RiggsFolly The OP changed the question: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34957526/revisions

Comment: Ahhh Apologise. **Naughty OP** I am guessing that `picathartes.com` is his site

Comment: Now I feel guilty about getting the accepted answer