# Check exist file with php

Tags: php, yii2

I want to check exist file with php or yii2

`filesize` and `is_file` and `file_exists` are not working !

`filesize` error is : `filesize(): stat failed for....`
`is_file` and `file_exists` return false !

This is my code :

```
 $fileI = $urlBase . "$home/../siteImage/$logo";
```

$fileI is :

```
http://localhost/iicitySite/web/index.php/../siteImage/parvaz.png
```

$home is :

```
 $home -> /iicitySite/web/index.php
```

This is has correct image in view :

```
      echo "



        <div class='col-lg-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 forsatItem'>
            <div class='backItem'>
                <div class='rightM col-lg-4'>
                    <div class='imgForsat'>
                        <img src='$home/../siteImage/$logo' alt=''/>
                    </div>
```

.
.
.
.

Comment: Is index.php an actual folder name on your server?

Comment: Might be you have to give permission to DIR where file stored. Please try it.

Comment: use echo `Yii::getAlias('@web').'/directoryName/ImageName';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com';//or file path
$headers = get_headers($url, 1);
print_r($headers);//$headers[0] u will get the status
```

Source: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/408420/3202287)

Answer (score 2):

If you are checking if file exist into server just you have to give the absolute path, I'm using \Yii::getAlias('@webroot') for get the absolute path and I'm executing this from a Controller.

This is my result into web browser.

Absolute Path:/home/hostinguser/public_html/files/temppdf/benja.pdf
The File /home/hostinguser/public_html/files/temppdf/benja.pdf Exists

```
        $pathFile = \Yii::getAlias('@webroot') .'/files/temppdf/' . 'benja.pdf'; 
        echo "<br>Absolute Path:" . $pathFile;
        if (file_exists($pathFile)) {
            echo "<br>The File $pathFile Exists";
        } else {
            echo "<br>The File $pathFile Do Not Exist";
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have checked and verified below code and it is working fine.

```
$filename = '/path/to/foo.txt';

if (file_exists($filename)) {
    echo "The file $filename exists";
} else {
    echo "The file $filename does not exist";
}
```

If you are not able to do this then the issue with your permission. Try to check file that are in desktop or some other permissible directory.

Hope this helps.

Comment: $filename = 'http://localhost/iicitySite/web/siteImage/parvaz.png';

                if (file_exists($filename)) {
                    echo "The file $filename exists";
                } else {
                    echo "The file $filename does not exist";
                }
die();


not working! 
   The file http://localhost/iicitySite/web/siteImage/parvaz.png does not exist

but this link has image when i checked that with url browser

Answer (score 1):

In you path you don't need the index.php but only the path

You can use this to get absolute(whole url including http) url :

```
 echo Url::to('@web/siteImage/parvaz.png', true);
 // http://codematrics.com/web/siteImage/parvaz.png
```

If you want to use relative(relative to current path) path than you can use this :

```
 echo Url::to('@web/siteImage/parvaz.png', true);images/logo.png
 // http://codematrics.com/web/siteImage/parvaz.png
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com'; // or file path
$headers = get_headers($url, 1);
print_r($headers);               // $headers[0] will get the status
```