# How to detect PHP script is being used as ErrorDocument for 404 Not Found?

Tags: php, http-status-code-404, server-response

Let's say I have a test.php file, configured to handle Apache 404 errors with `ErrorDocument 404 /test.php`

What PHP code do I have to add to check if we're really handling a 404, and test.php has not been called directly?

Like:

```
<?php
if (server_response_code == 404) {
    echo "It's a 404!"
}
?>
```

P.S. There's no 404 forwarding or so…

Comment: Can you clarify - Do you want to determine the response code of an HTTP request you've made to another server from PHP?

It sounds like you want the response code for the request you are currently handling, and that would normally be 200 OK, unless you override it using header()

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/408405/easy-way-to-test-a-url-for-404-in-php for checking remote URLs for 404 responses

Comment: @Paul Dixon I mean: How can I check if a current url is 404 or not?

Comment: I do not want to check remote URL's. I want to check the URL where the code is on.

Comment: The fact that you are processing it in a script means it's not a 404 by default. You can return a 404 response with header() - see M Maavia's answer below for an example.

Comment: Okay, I'll try to explain: I have this in my `.htaccess`: `ErrorDocument 404 /`. `www.example.com/existing_file.php` will open `existing_file.php`  and response server code 200. But `www.example.com/NOT_existing_file.php` will redirect to main path (`/`) und send a 404 server response code. How can I now echo "It's 404!" e.g.?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to set your ErrorDocument to a special script, e.g. 404.php? Then you know you're handling a 404! Otherwise, in your main script you'll have to look the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] and similar vars to see if you can detect if the request would have been a 404.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134235/discussion-between-user7128548-and-paul-dixon).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this would be simply look at the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and determine if it points at something invalid.

While your example is probably simplified for this question, it might be as simple as

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != 'test.php') {
    //we are handling a 404
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    echo "These aren't the droids you're looking for";
}
```

You may need more complex logic, but will all boil down to looking at the request and detecting it was invalid.

As long as the ErrorDocument is a relative URL (doesn't start with http://...), then you should find your script has some extra $_SERVER variables, e.g.

```
$_SERVER["REDIRECT_URL"]; // /original/path
$_SERVER['REDIRECT_STATUS']; // 404
```

See the [ErrorDocument](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html) documentation for more details.

Alternatively, just pass a query string arg to the 404 handler, e.g. `ErrorDocument 404 /test.php?error=404` :)

Comment: Thanks, solution was to add `ErrorDocument 404 /?404=yes` in my `.htaccess` and the following in my file: `<?php
if (isset($_GET['404'])) {
 include "content/404.php";
}
?>`.